# Using fancybox with different DOM stucture

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I want to able to use fancybox with below DOM structure.

```
<div>
 <img src="smallImageSource" rel="bigImageSource">
 <img src="smallImageSource" rel="bigImageSource">
 <img src="smallImageSource" rel="bigImageSource">
<div>
```

I want to provide big image sources in rel attributes or any other data attributes.

Comment: 1) Why? 2) If it doesn't mention it in the fancybox documentation it won't work. Unless you loop through each element and wrap it in an `a` element with the link in it.

Comment: Already i am using it with anchors but there are some problems with other compenents which use same structure in sametime. That is why i want to be able to use different structure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the way of fancybox reading it, I would create a javascript that turns your dom structure into the way fancybox likes it.

for example:

```
$('img').each(function () {
$this = $(this);
$this.wrap('<a href="'+$this.attr('rel')+'"></a>');
$this.removeAttr('rel');
});
// run fancybox
```

Comment: This is only suggestion. I am aware of that but i have total valid reasons for to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just apply a container with a class specifically for fancybox.

You can then target the elements in your styling that will be fancybox only styles